# add subview in navigation bar ios7

Tags: ios, ios7

I want to add two button and a image view on navigation bar. I written following code for adding image but it is not working.

```
 UIView *customView=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 44)];
 UIImageView *logo=[[UIImageView alloc]init];
 logo.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"sdas.jpeg"];
[customView addSubview:logo];
self.navigationController.navigationItem.titleView=customView;
```

Comment: You can hide navigation bar and can take custom UIView of size of UiNavigation bar. Then you can add subview to it according to your need.

Comment: no do not want to hide i want all on uinavigation bar

Comment: I suggest you a way, Now it`s Depends on you:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `initWithCustomView` to add buttons as describe [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12137345/uibarbuttonitem-init-with-custom-view-selector-not-working-properly), and `setBackgroundImage:forMetrics` using [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7764309/changing-the-uinavigationbar-background-image).

Comment: I want to add two separate buttons and a uiimage in between but i am not able to see the image even plz help

Comment: do it in steps, using first link create a button and assign it to leftbarbutton item.

Comment: Great to see this. :) If any of the answer helped you, marked it as answer so it would be helpful for future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Your Image Name"]];
```